# Cannot publish Google App with same name of Suspended App

Tags: android, publish

I all.

I need to publish an Android App with name "MY_APP_NAME" and applicationId "XXX.DUMMY.DOMAIN.APP" on Google Play Store.

The problem is that i have a suspended App in my app list with the same name.

I tried to create a new one with the same name and different applicationId (and package name) of the supended one.

Google not allows me to create a new Application with the same name and i got the error:

> You have to choose a different title for your app. This is already the
>   title of XXX.DUMMY.DOMAIN.APP.

I cannot unpublish, remove or rename the [suspended app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBGO4.png).

How can i create a new App with the same name (and different applicationId and package name)?

Can I remove the suspended app?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like `You have to choose a different title for your app` as google says. Looks like there is no way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me before. You can create another application with the different `App ID`, but you can name it as it was before, even with the same icon. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is it safe to re-publish the app with different package ID but same name?

In the email Google says:

```
Sign in to your Play Console and submit the updated, policy compliant app using a new package name and a new app name.
```

but then again:

1. they tore down the apps because they didnt like some of the code
2. I am resubmitting the apps without the offending code
3. Surely based on that they will find this acceptable and will be able to see this from our submission? Its quite important for me to save my app name.

Anyone got any experience with similar situation?